# Country name in English

Tags: android, locale

I am trying to get country name from country code. For example:

Locale locale = new Locale("", "FR");
   locale.getDisplayName()

So, I get France. But, when my phone in other language, it get the name in local language. So when my phone is in Hebrew I get צרפת which in Hebrew is France.
But I wish to get the name always in English. I have tried:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US", "FR");
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "FR");
```

But It just not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the English locale as parameter to the method as following:

```
String france = new Locale("", "FR").getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH); // France
```

Or the method you used:

```
String france = new Locale("", "FR").getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH); // France
```